# JasperXml Count Function within group is working fine in Jasper Studio Preview but why it is not working when i integrate it to PHP?

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I created jasperxml report in jasper studio, the report consist of data group by year and sub group by religion. In the group footer, i inserted count function to count rows inside year group, and also i inserted count function to count rows inside religion sub group. All are working fine using jasper studio report preview, then i integrated the (.jrxml) to my php application, the report is running but the count functions are not working, they are not counting the rows accurately.

Answer (score -2):

i used this to solve this problem, $V{groupname_COUNT}, where groupname is the name of your group.
http://www.brianburridge.com/2005/04/14/row-count-within-a-group/